# Beautiful Soup 4 find method returns 'None'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

username = input('enter username: ')

url = f'https://www.tiktok.com/@{username}'
response = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
subname = soup.find('h1', class_="share-sub-title")
print(subname)
```

It doens't matter what i search for it just returns 'none'. Please help me out ive been searching for this solution for the past 3 days and i can't find it. I am also new to coding so my apologies.

Comment: try printing the response and verify if you actually get the response you are expecting.

Comment: In fact you are getting nothing in `response` just an empty string. try using `selenium`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the problem in your code but you can try this. Add header in you request object.

```
headers = {}
headers['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686)"
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
```